# Is there any alternative to NVIDIA graphics card for deep learning with GPU computing?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gpu, convolution

Now I am working on a deep learning problem. I am trying to use Convolutional neural network in matlab. But the documentation says, we need NVIDIA graphics card for gpu computing.

My laptop has Intel HD graphics 2600 card for graphics processing. So can someone advise any other options we have in this case to run the deep learning algorithms and convnet algorithms.

Can i run those algorithms without GPU computing and what will be the effect(in time difference).

Comment: You may get something working with some other GPU cards, but, truth is, NVIDIA is ahead of any other company in GPU computing.

Answer (score 4):

You are not going to be able to achieve much with an integrated Intel graphics card. First, most deep learning frameworks use CUDA to implement GPU computations and CUDA is supported only by the NVidia GPUs. There were several attempts to extend the standard deep learning frameworks to OpenCL, notably Theano has an [incomplete OpenCL backend](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/tutorial/using_gpu.html) and Caffe has been [ported to OpenCL](https://github.com/amd/OpenCL-caffe) by the AMD research lab. However, these are either incomplete at this point or not as actively maintained.

The other issue is performance. Depending on your application, you might require a much better GPU than what your laptop can provide. It is not uncommon to use multi-GPU machines equipped with NVidia Titans to train networks for days or even weeks.

My recommendation is to either buy a dedicated machine for deep learning computations (a single GPU machine with the just released NVidia GTX 1080 can be purchased for the price of a standard laptop) or rent GPU instances on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Googles Tensor Processing Units with Google Colab where you can get a GPU for "free" they have a pretty cool cloud GPU [technology](https://cloud.google.com/gpu)

- You can stat working with your google accounts 
  with a Jupiter notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb
- Kaggle (Google Owned Data Science competition site) also has this option to create Jupiter notebooks + GPU, but only in limited cases:

  - notebooks: https://www.kaggle.com/kernels
  - Documentation for it: https://www.kaggle.com/docs/notebooks